# Memory leak issue in navigation controller

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

I am doing memory leak testing. The tool indicates a leak in line 2 of the code below. What is the reason?

```
DailySales *ds = [[DailySales alloc] initWithNibName:@"DailySales" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ds animated:YES];
[ds release];
```

Comment: Does it say what type of object is leaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. Are you running in the simulator or on the device? Running Instruments on the simulator can produce false leak reports.

Comment: i am testing in simulator .What is the difference in testing simulator and device.Thank you

Comment: when i am testing in device it shows following error:  Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: You'll need to get a Developer provisioning profile from the Apple Developer Center, install it, and tell your project to use it for Debug builds in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Objects loaded from the NIB are leaking. Check your outlets and see if they are carefully `release`d in dealloc.