# Navigation Controller not releasing memory, memory leak?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

Ive created a navigation which pushes a view controller that contains an image view and a button which adds the same view controller each time the button is tapped. After each tap the memory grows and after each back tap the memory is not released despite `deinit` being called. There is nothing in the code that points to a memory leak is there something I am missing thank you?

[complete project repository](https://github.com/TheRedCamaro30/Leaky-Navigation-Controller)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


     lazy var nextButton:UIButton? = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return button
    }()

     lazy var imageView:UIImageView? = {
        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DJI_0014")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        guard let imageView = self.imageView, let nextButton = self.nextButton else{
            print("imageView, nextButton are nil")
            return
        }

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.topAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)])

        view.addSubview(nextButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            nextButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)])
    }

    @objc func nextButtonTapped(){
        print("next button tapped")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController(), animated: true)
    }

    deinit {
        print("view controller is deinitialized")
    }

}
```

Ive viewed other questions listed below and tried to adopt their suggestions but none of them seemed to help

[Navigation arc memory not released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862231/navigation-arc-memory-not-released)

[Memory leak issue in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169330/memory-leak-issue-in-navigation-controller)

[image: Memory Degbugger]

Comment: use a real iPhone not simulator and run a long time test , For example 100 pushes and pops and you will find it has a cap memory and stable below 18M(It depends on the size of image.).

Comment: @E.Coms Thank you for taking the time to run it and look through it. Ive been performing all on tests on an iPhone X and an iPhone 6s Plus. I suspected the image as well so I removed the image in my tests. After running about 20-30 pushes consecutively and 20-30 consecutive pops the memory appears to grow in the memory debugger like a mountain there is a spike especially after the first pop. There are leaks reported in profiler but Ive read those can be misleading and Ive looked through the memory graph but haven't found anything helpful its a very strange phenomenon.

Comment: I believe there are more codes and resources  in your projects. It's a normal situation like this as it will be handled by system, like caching and animation optimizations.  The code presented here should be fine. If there is no other bug and leaks, it will reach peaks at around 40-50M. Unless there is any leaks you may overlooked.  Also you may consider to popToRoot in time. It's a rare condition to just  keep pushing so many vcs. Maybe 10 layers is big enough. You can change the content of VCs, not vc it self.

Comment: @E.Coms I have added a link to the repository of the complete project so you can see for yourself https://github.com/TheRedCamaro30/Leaky-Navigation-Controller. There is no reason that I can think of for why the views shouldn't behave as expected where the memory is released as the user swipes off a ViewController. In Theory the user should be able to add a significant number of views to the naviagtion controller as long as deallocations are being handled responsibly.

Comment: As I said, if you hide the navigation bar and turn off all animations. The maximum memory is about 22M and can added up 100 layer+ without any problem. If you turn on  the animations and navigtionbar is shown with a back button, The maximum should be 35M. The reason of peak is due to save some spaces for animation controllers and related.  There is one time such jumping and never happen again.

Comment: When I tried it without animations and navigation bar after 200 layers you were right it leveled at 22-23M, when layers were removed it eventually went down to around 19M.  When i put the animations and navigtionbar back on and repeated the 200 layers the memory increased to around 38 M, which is totally fine but when i removed the layers the memory remained at 38M. Is this what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have identified the problem, which is from the navigationBar:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

This code will remove all the issues on large memory residues. Other parts of codes are fine. and in this situation, all memory will keep around 19M all the time.

I tried to use a navigationDelegate to do the transition and found there is a crash overlooked by the system and stated that if repeating push vc will make NavigationBar not layout well. So I turn it hidden and the problem has gone. But if you do need navigationBar or its animation, there would be a lot of work to do here.

But the memory issue has been found.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! We noticed the same thing when the bar and animation is removed the memory will decrease  back down to where it had started.  When just adding in the animation for the push and pop the memory does not go down nearly as much as it went up. Do you think this is a bug that should be filed with apple?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I am a bit stumped as well. I am wondering if this is a related issue with the collectionview, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349341/memory-is-not-released-during-perform-batch-updates-in-collectionview